# 'a' and 'the' confusion

Tags: articles

I am not native English speaker. I get frustrated when it come to articles. Can you please tell me whether the sentence below is grammatically correct.

> She spent all the night in rereading a letter from her sister

Comment: I would say, "She spent all night rereading a letter from her sister."

Comment: Better answers for this will probably be found at https://ell.stackexchange.com ... "spent all the night" NO.  "spent all night" YES. "spent the night" YES.  "spent the whole night" YES.  "spent the long cold frustrating night" YES.

Comment: That must have been one heck of a letter.

Comment: 'Spent all the night' is unidiomatic. 'Spent all night' is better, but still sounds less than optimal here;. 'Spent the night' sounds like it was a trivial pastime. 'Spent the whole night' is spot on, carrying emphasis, conveying the sense of urgency.